# Will a Keystone KE-3800 flash unit damage a new DSLR?

Tags: dslr, hotshoe-flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can using an old flash damage a new DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19204/can-using-an-old-flash-damage-a-new-dslr)

I was wondering if an old flash (specifically "keystone ke-3800", which I haven't been able to find in Google) will work on my new Canon t4i DSLR.

Is there any chance one will damage the other? (different voltage, etc). The connector seems to be the same, so logic tells me there is a standard and nothing should fry.

Comment: I think this is a good question so I've voted you up, but I do believe the linked to question above answers this generally speaking. What do you think?