# Can I use an old Sunpak flash usefully on a DSLR?

Tags: flash, olympus, hotshoe-flash, manual-flash

I'm a photo beginner and I'm having a Olympus E1 and looking for an inexpensive shoe flash.

As usual I found before digital days camera flash from eBay for a reasonable amount and having some questions.

SUNPAK AUTO 24DX

1. Does TTL metering would available with this.
2. Mostly I assume TTL metering wouldn't available for this. So is there any possibility or a practical way of using this after referring the ASN, distance readings from the back of the flasher body?[image: back side of the sunpak auto 24dx]

I mean, in practical photographic session, do photographers use hardware materials like this?

Comment: Relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/19204/9161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Would] TTL metering would available with this?**

No. The Sunpak 24DX was made in the days before TTL became prevalent in flash technology. That doesn't mean you can't use it in an automated mode, however, since it has an autothyristor (Auto) mode.  You set the iso and aperture setting you're using on the camera, and the flash can use an external sensor to automate the cutoff of the light output. It's what photographers used to automate flash power setting before TTL.

**Is there any possibility or a practical way of using this after referring the ASN, distance readings from the back of the flasher body?back side of the sunpak auto 24dx**

Yes. You might be able to use it, it's just not as easy to use as a modern TTL-capable flash like, say a Nissin i40 or Olympus FL-600R/Panasonic FL360L, and there are a lot of brand new cheap flashes around that will work in full manual or TTL around.  So, purchasing a used unit with more limited capabilities may not be the the best purchase.

**I mean, in practical photographic session, do photographers use hardware like this?**

Yes, some do.  I'm googling up a sync voltage on the 24DX of 11V, so it should be safe for the E1 (i.e., won't fry the camera hotshoe with super-high voltages, like some vintage flashes have).  But.  The feature set on this flash isn't particularly good, especially for on-camera usage. It has no tilt, it has no swivel. It can only deliver direct flash.

See also: [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/what-features-should-one-look-for-when-selecting-a-flash)

This might give you an idea of why it could well be worth saving up to have a higher budget to go shopping for a flash.  A flash can be far more transformative to your photography than any lens--it may be appropriate to budget accordingly.

Comment: wonderful. I'll search for another product. That camera frying thing is scary. I just heard that. Previously also I lost a Olymp-E410 body.

Comment: how do you see this product [VIVITAR 550FD auto thyristor](http://www.ebay.com/itm/VIVITAR-550FD-auto-thyristor-Flash-unit-M-P-O-for-Pentax-Minolta-Olympus-550-FD-/400995904793?hash=item5d5d37ed19:g:9hEAAOxyONBSXjjp)

Comment: @inckka We don't typically do product recommendations here on photo.SE, because they're too individual or go out of date quickly. Go through the features list question. That'll give you a basis for how to judge the suitability of a given flash for what you want to do.  Personally, I'd save up for a Panasonic FL360L/Oly FL-600R (same flash and what I want for my GX-7), but then, you're not me.

Answer (score 1):

1) No, it does not do TTL metering.

2) It is possible to use this flash with your camera but you must use the camera in manual mode and then match the aperture to the settings on the flash.

I would not buy this flash because there are cheap TTL flashes avaialble on ebay which would be easier to use.

This one is only about $26: [Cheap ebay Olympus TTL flash](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Flashes-Flash-Accessories-/64353/i.html?_sop=15&_from=R40&_nkw=Dedicated%20TTL%20Flash%20for%20Olympus&_dcat=64353&rt=nc&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=15&_udhi=30)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, 99.99% of the time I use aperture priority. So I will set the settings manually on flash. Also regarding the recommended product, isn't the SUNPAK has a high guide number?

Comment: I would not use use aperture priority because the shutter speed will be too slow in low light conditions.  The Sunpak Auto 24DX has a guide number of 24m (or 80 feet). That is not considered a powerful flash. The built in flash on many cameras has a Guide Number of 13m while most larger external flash units have a Guide Number of 43m or even 58m.